# ToolBar and StatusBar overlap in the Tabbed activity in an unmodified newly created project in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-toolbar, android-coordinatorlayout, android-tabbed-activity

I created a new project with a `Tabbed Activity` and navigation style `Action Bar Tabs`.

The `MainActivity`'s  default layout is as follows on which i swipe from the `TabLayout` as follows:

[image]

**After swiping all the way up it looks like this:**
The `ToolBar` and `StatusBar` are overlapping!

[image]

**Questions:**

Is this the expected behavior? Shouldn't the scrolling be disabled or if enabled, the toolbar should hide (e.g. whatsapp)? This default behavior appears buggy to me. Did i miss something that led to this?

And if this is the default expected behavior? how can do the following?

- Disable the scrolling in `CoordinatorLayout`?
- Hide the `ToolBar` when scrolling is enabled?

**PS:** Like i mentioned this is an unmodified new project (no changes from my end). If someone still needs the generated code I'll share.

Comment: No, is not the expected behaviour. Looks like you have a transparency in the status bar. A color without alpha should fix it. That's just my guess, but would help to have the xml code and (if apply, if you are modifying something programmatically) the java code.

Comment: nothing modified at all. just created the project and run.

Comment: @Sotti which xml would you like me to share?

Comment: Do you have enabled to window to draw status bar?

Comment: @NikolaDespotoski sorry did not understand.

Comment: Which version of Android Studio are you using? I couldn't reproduce it because the tabbed activity in Android Studio 2 Beta 2 doesn't have the tabs... If you could share the code, it would help.

Comment: @Sotti you have to select the `Action Bar Tabs` option from the dropdown in the last screen in the wizard when creating new project to get the tabs. Btw, I'm on the latest on stable channel i.e. 1.5.1

Comment: But, like I've said before, if you go to /v21/styles.xml you'll see in in your theme a line like this: <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>. Instead of the transparent color, use the primaryDark color (replace that line bye <item name="android:statusBarColor">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>).

Comment: @Sotti Excellent! That was it. Working fine now. Thanks! (You might want to post an answer for this so that i can accept.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to /v21/styles.xml and replace:

```
<item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
```

by:

```
<item name="android:statusBarColor">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
```

The problem is that the status bar is transparent.

Note: By default, the status bar uses the primaryDarkColor if it's defined. So in this case, you could remove that line in order to use the primaryDarkColor as far as you keep this line...

```
<item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
```

...in the values\styles.xml in your AppTheme.